# Python/SQL Inserting multiple variables into param and having multiple params

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to store variables from a python function within an sqlite3 database. I'm not sure if the way i am handling the parameters is correct. There are no syntax errors but I am getting a 500 error page.

`title`, `hightemp`, `lowtemp` and `desc` are column names. The table is called `weatherforecast`.

When the questionable code is removed, the page loads normally.

Of course, I have a connection string and I am mapping the variables to the outputs of functions correctly, but they are not necessary for the snippet.

```
    params = {'title'[
          : day1titlevar,
          : day2titlevar,
          : day3titlevar,
          : day4titlevar,
          : day5titlevar,
          : day6titlevar],

          'hightemp'[
          : day1highvar,
          : day2highvar,
          : day3highvar,
          : day4highvar,
          : day5highvar,
          : day6highvar],

          'lowtemp'[
          : day1lowvar,
          : day2lowvar,
          : day3lowvar,
          : day4lowvar,
          : day5lowvar,
          : day6lowvar],

          'desc'[
          : day1descvar,
          : day2descvar,
          : day3descvar,
          : day4descvar,
          : day5descvar,
          : day6descvar]

          }

db.execute("insert into weatherforecast values(:day1titlevar,:day1highvar,:day1lowvar,:day1descvar,:day2titlevar,:day2highvar,:day2lowvar,:day2descvar,:day3titlevar,:day3highvar,:day3lowvar,:day3descvar,:day4titlevar,:day4highvar,:day4lowvar,:day4descvar,:day5titlevar,:day5highvar,:day5lowvar,:day5descvar,:day6titlevar,:day6highvar,:day6lowvar,:day6descvar);", params)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: You are missing `:` after key names in `param` dict definition.

Comment: You need to add the columns after weatherforecast inside parenthesis.

Comment: And you are trying to insert 6 rows of data at once

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to base your code in something like this:

```
data = [dict(day=1,temp=25),
        dict(day=2,temp=22),
        dict(day=3,temp=19)]

for measure in data: # just for visual check
    print(measure['day'],measure['temp'])

for measure in data:
    db.execute('insert into forecast("day", "temp") values(:day,:temp);', measure)
```